# Transpose matrix in ANSI C

Tags: performance, c, matrix

Is there a way to transpose a matrix in `ANSI C` way much better than this `ANSI C` code?
Can I do transpose in a different and faster way?

The focus of this aim is: **Speed**

```
/*
 * Turn A into transponse A^T
 * A[row * column]
 */
void tran(float A[], size_t row, size_t column) {
    /* Decleration */
    float *B = (float*)malloc(row * column * sizeof(float));
    float* transpose = NULL;
    float *ptr_A = A;
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        transpose = &B[i];
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            *transpose = *ptr_A;
            ptr_A++;
            transpose += row;
        }
    }

    /* Copy! */
    memcpy(A, B, row*column*sizeof(float));

    /* Free */
    free(B);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Performance

To get the best performance on contemporary CPUs you need a very good understanding of the memory and cache systems, the prefetcher, and if vector instructions can be used. The best algorithm to use will also depend on the size of the matrix.

There are also some performance issues caused by the language itself, and I recommend you target at least C99 so you can use [`restrict`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

You are also creating a temporary matrix and copying it back at the end. This has some overhead that could be avoided in two ways:

- Don't modify `A[]` at all, but let the caller supply a `B[]` where the result will be stored.
- Modify `A[]` [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition). This is rather easy for square matrices, but it will quickly become complicated for non-square matrices. Still, you could do the in-place method for square ones and fall back to your original code for non-square ones.

## Naming things

The names of the function and the variable names could be improved. Most importantly, I would make sure the function is named `transpose()`. Unnecessary abbreviations can cause confusion later on. The variable `transpose` must then be renamed of course, at first glance a better name would just be `ptr_B`.

`row` and `column` are singular, so it sounds like those are row and column *indices*, not *counts*. `rows` and `columns` would be better, or if you want to be even more explicit, `num_rows` and `num_columns`. Once you have done that, you can rename `i` and `j` to `row` and `column`.

## Simplified code

The code can be greatly simplified by using C99 and using `[]` instead of pointer arithmetic:

```
void transpose(const float *restrict input, float *restrict output,
               size_t num_rows, size_t num_columns)
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
        for (size_t column = 0; column < num_columns; column++)
            output[column * num_rows + row] = input[row * num_columns + column];
}
```

An optimizing compiler will generate [similar assembly code](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2Bxithzlj2iltF5IJezwWO0Xoe3uZ/GI8rwLr2GgtMZljj2WuzeA2qK8yNpawZSdFEL5DqdmAzGwAbKiUUWMQmrdXkyR5doM1nw3t%2Bx9dS5Gtn46Xi%2BXK0zu9X2fbHUkGyHBQHiEHOwvq5vt9Pp%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%2BLBZYgeYWjaOwIAcEZPDifxJkKYo9CdXI0g8wPsmSSoGG6UO%2BgGcp3vacYA70b3446OpE96KIBgz6Os/GfPpkLr3apWCQCqK/rAcqjg9lUAAOJtlabSQ9mAZBkHlL5XAYNraQgXBCF7J4uFmXhxq0M1SA6rqeo4PrSCprgNG60ryqb4bRqalqF4JrwG93obD4mheXeSOxJCAA%3D%3D) for the loop.

Comment: My code is going to be used with C++, so I cannot use C99. Sorry, but thanks for the advice about restrict.

Comment: You can most likely use `restrict`, or at least some version of it, in C++ as well, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776283/5481471). You can always define a macro for it that expands to `restrict`, `__restrict__` or nothing depending on what the compiler supports.

Comment: Will it be faster if you did `input += num_columns` instead? Then you don't need the multiplication `*` statement.

Comment: No, the compiler will already do that for you automatically; it's called [strength reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction), and is a very basic optimization. I recommend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4) to get an idea of what the compiler does for you.

Comment: But your two for-loops resulting less assebly code than my two for-loops. Perhaps I should not use strength reduction by my self.

Comment: Don't worry about strength reduction and other micro-optimizations unless you really know better than the compiler and need to get every bit of performance out of the CPU that is possible. Focus first on the *algorithm*, and make sure it is an efficient one. Here it's quite trivial, you can't do better than an \$O(N)\$ algorithm, where \$N\$ is the number of elements in the matrix. Then try to make sure the code is simple and clear. After that you should run benchmarks to see how fast your code is, and also so you can make a change and see if that improved things or not.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your advices. Early optimization is the root of evil.